# Extend number of PWM pins on an arduino?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm

How do I extend the number of PWM pins on an Arduino without using software solutions, I need 32 to drive 32 mosfets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an Arduino with that many hardware PWM outputs.

You could use a couple of extension boards with a PCA9685 chip. Each has 16 12bit PWM channels.

There are a few boards available from Adafruit.

Comment: any other? I cant get that IC

Comment: @Seeker Sure you can! Over 13000 in stock! https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/NXP-Semiconductors/PCA9685PW118?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvKM5ialpXrmnWDpPMxsdrM

Comment: How do you know I can? god this is annoying...

Comment: I can only buy from a specific vendor my company has a contract with, and they don't have this specific IC..

Answer (score 0):

SX1509, 16 PWM outputs, I2C control.

https://www.semtech.com/uploads/documents/sx150x_89b.pdf

Sparkfun has them on a breakout board already, may even have links to an Arduino library for it.

> Integrated LED Driver for Enhanced Lighting
>
> Intensity Control (256-step PWM)
>
> Blink Control (224 On/Off values)
>
> Breathing Control (224 Fade In/Out values)

2 Address lines also, so 4 of them can be on the I2C bus for 64 PWM outputs without committing any additional MCU pins.